# How do I implement Breezejs server-side for WebAPIv2 and EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I have tried to do some research of how to implement Breezejs for the use in one of my applications.
The problem is that I cant really find any documentation of how to properly implement breezejs.. are there any specific actions thats required on my controller to be able to fully use breezejs for instance?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze.js implements the OData client protocol.
http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/introduction

Web Api / Ef6 have built in support for exposing data as OData, you just need to configure it:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api